# Emberjs loading dynamic subview

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just getting started with emberjs and I have some problems understanding how to dynamically change views within a view.

I want to have a page with a calendar.
This page has some buttons on the top to switch between different calendar views (day, week, month) and some filter options for the appointments within this view.

See this mockup:
[image]

Currently I have created a calendar route and a CalendarIndexView and template.
This template will contain the basic filter and view toggle buttons.
Within the index view I can call another view to display the grid.

```
<div class="calendar-container">
  {{view monthView}}
</div>
```

The collection/context that is attached to these different views should not change because the filter is also applied on this.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to change the monthView to for example dayView after the "day" button is clicked.
Should I handle this in a router, controller or in the main calendar view?
If not view the router, how would make this view switching dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the core strengths of Ember is the router - everything is driven by the URL. I don't think you should part from that.

1. Use different routes for the different views within a calendar resource (in the router):

   ```
   this.resource('calendar', { path: '/calendar' }, function() {
     this.route('day');
     this.route('week');
     this.route('month');
   });
   ```
2. Set the model on the calendar resource
3. In the nested routes (`day`, `week` *(you could make month the default by using the `calendar index route` for it)*), use the same model as in the calendar route, just filter it down to what you want. e.g.:

   ```
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function() {
       return this.modelFor('calendar').filter(function(event) { ... });
     }
   });
   ```
4. For the people filter create a computed property in the controller that filters the events on the model and use that in the templates instead of the actual model. In that, if a person is selected, you can filter out any events without that person.

   ```
   selectedPerson: null, // bind that e.g. to a select with all the people or change that with an action

   filteredEvents: function() {
     if (! this.get('selectedPerson')) {
       return this.get('events');
     }
     return this.get('events').filterBy('attendee', this.get('selectedPerson'));
   }.property('events.@each.attendee', 'selectedPerson')
   ```
5. Better than (4.): Do the filtering via [query parameters](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/). That way, you could be very flexible and even build powerful text search pretty easily...

Hope that helps and happy to see different approaches...

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, this definitely helps!